# Adding Comments box in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I want to add Comment box in HTML5 canvas where user can type on that box. 
I want a functionality whenever add a comment box from a toolbar above the canvas area, then it is added as a TextArea like control (ie. editable and cursor focus will be there so that i can auto type) & if i will click anywhere else then focus will be removed from this textarea and it just becomes Text.

Like the image given below:

[image]

Comment: @HelderSepulveda why i have to submit the code in this question. The question i am asking as i dont know the exact way to acheive the solution to this. Because as per my knowledge. i cannot add a text area like control on the image canvas which becomes like editable. Opening a popup is a solution but i dont want to open the popup.

Comment: Adding your current code shows that you atleast tried to do it yourself. Without any code its highly unlikely anyone will help you because then they would just be coding for you.

Comment: @Granny i dont want anyone to code for me. I am looking for a route or whether this is possible or not as you can see what i think in my last comment. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: It has to be canvas? Because it would be easier to do it with SVG or HTML map

Comment: @enxaneta I am not aware that I can add Textbox like control in SVG OR HTML Map. If you can provide any sample that'll be really helpful. Please note I want it to be editable.

Comment: The textbox can be an HTML element set outside of the SVG element. But SVG accept HTML <foreignObject>s if is a must.

Comment: @enxaneta Ok thanks, I'll try to test this that it solves my problem & will update here later.